When using matplotlib to display graphics, graphics are unresponsive and the error message is: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'
When using matplotlib in Visual Studio Code to display graphics, graphics are unresponsive and the error message as follows:
Failed to enable GUI event loop integration for 'qt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.8.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\matplotlibtools.py", line 30, in do_enable_gui
    enable_gui(guiname)
  File "~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.8.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\inputhook.py", line 540, in enable_gui
    return gui_hook(app)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.8.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\inputhook.py", line 176, in enable_qt
    from pydev_ipython.qt_for_kernel import QT_API, QT_API_PYQT5
  File "~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.8.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\qt_for_kernel.py", line 116, in <module>
    QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg, QT_API = load_qt(api_opts)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.8.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\qt_loaders.py", line 276, in load_qt
    if not can_import(api):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.8.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\qt_loaders.py", line 152, in can_import
    if not has_binding(api):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.8.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\qt_loaders.py", line 115, in has_binding
    import imp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'
Backend QtAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.

My code is as follows (the original code has been processed, the code that can trigger this bug is as follows):
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
  data = torch.arange(1, 10)
  plt.plot(data)
  plt.title('label name')
  # ……

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

When using plt.ion() it didn't work.

Hi Hui Xiao, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also can I answer my own question..
, Just a reminder :)

This may be due to the matplotlib backend being set incorrectly. Setting the matplotlib backend to 'TkAgg' in my code, which is generally the most widely supported graphics backend.
I tried this in my code and it worked, this might be caused by a vscode bug:
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
plt.ion()

The total code is like fowlloing:
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
plt.ion()

def main():
  data = torch.arange(1, 10)
  plt.plot(data)
  plt.title('label name')
  # ……

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

